# Python yield generator function

Tags: python, generator, yield, yield-return, yield-keyword

So I've got this ginormous humungous class, of which the only relevant code is:

```
    def get_col_is_numeric(self, col_name):
        "Returns an iterator with each cell length in the named column"
        min(self.get_col_iter_is_numeric(col_name))
```

... and I loaded some values into the dict from a csv file.
Problem is that csvDictReaderCol.get_col_is_numeric('Ann_payrll') returns None
even though all values in the column are numbers.
Why does yield generate a None value?

Comment: Use some debugging tools. If you don't have a debugger arrange that you just print out all the local variables, parameters etc. whenever you encounter `yield None`.

Comment: What's the difference between your class and `csv.DictReader` -- why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @katrielalex You are correct! It's the same. Though I think I was using this with an earlier version of Python (I think it was 2.3 before upgrading) and cvs.DictReader was not available on that Python version at the time.  Using Python 2.6 and cvs.DictReader is available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

get_col_is_numeric is missing a return statement so it returns None.

Also next time, try just posting the actual functions/methods involved rather then the whole class.